# Is there an event listener for jms message expiration?

Tags: glassfish, jms

I'm currently working on jms message using the default broker from glassfish. Example I have a queueA.

queueA, will receive 2 types of response:

1.) normal response - meaning the service replies immediately without any problem,

2.) expired response - service replies after 2days.

On the queueA, I have a jms receiver that times out after 5mins, so after that no one will pickup the message and it will timeout after 30s. The question is, can I throw an event when this event happens so that I can handle the delayed response?

Thanks,

czetsuya

Comment: Just FYI: WebSphere MQ has option to set to fire notification message when a message expires. They are called "Report Options" and must on the header of the message being sent along with name of the queue where notification message needs to be sent after a message expires.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, I found out that there is no message expiration action that will be thrown by glassfish when this event occurs. My work around is to use 2 queues synchronous and asynchronous, that will be read synchronously, if the message is already gone then write to the asynchronous queue.

SenderA writes to AsynchronousQueueA
SenderA starts reading SynchronousQueueResponseS (for n seconds)
ReceiverA receives message from SenderA to AsynchronousQueueA
ReceiverA writes a reply to SynchronousQueueResponseS
  if failed then write a reply to AsynchronousQueueResponseA.

Take note that the thread listening to SynchronousQueueResponseS will expire in n seconds, if it does the reply will be written to AsynchronousQueueResponseA. This is a solution for a queue expiration event listener.